facing invalid credentials error while implementing oauth2login authentication using microservice architecture through API gateway
I have two services i.e. API-gateway which is running on port 6051 and auth-service which is running on 6052 port. I have added dependency and configuration in auth-service and sets redirect url which consist of port 6051. But when request goes to google authentication via API gateway then it will give me Invalid credential error.enter image description here
I tried to implement oauth2login in API gateway service but facing an issue in security filter chain where authentication is not able to authenticate google oauth in same method as where jwt authentication is already implemented.  Given code uses serverhttpsecurity but won't able to authenticate google account when request hits to "auth-service/social/*" -
http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
        .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)))
        .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable()
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
        .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/auth-service/auth/**").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/auth-service/login/**").permitAll()
    .and().authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/auth-service/social/**").authenticated().and().oauth2Login();

